# Is it possible to put database in the cnf file To secure mysqldump

Tags: mysql

I have a working cron job to backup the databases on a daily basis. I want to secure the authentication details in a mysql config file for **mysqldump** using **--defaults-extra-file**.

I know I can do the following

```
[mysqldump]
host = hostname
user = username
password = password
```

**How can I also store the database name in it ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is **no**.  I have

1. Read the information at dev.mysql.com
2. Read the article at tutorialspoint
3. Tried the --help command
4. Tried a line **database=mydatabase**